# InvalidDocumentError: Invalid data to create a `Source` instance. syncStatus - 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: django, datetime, mongoengine

I keep getting the following issue when trying to query the collection described below:

```
class HistorySync(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    status = StringField()
    oldestDate = DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overload constructor to deal with history sync status documents"""
        if 'oldestDate' in kwargs:
            kwargs['oldestDate'] = dateparser.parse(kwargs['oldestDate'])

        super(DynamicEmbeddedDocument, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class SyncStatus(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    status = StringField()
    synchedAt = DateTimeField()
    newestDate = DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overload constructor to deal with most recent sync status documents"""
        if 'synchedAt' in kwargs:
            kwargs['synchedAt'] = dateparser.parse(kwargs['synchedAt'])

        if 'newestDate' in kwargs:
            kwargs['newestDate'] = dateparser.parse(kwargs['newestDate'])

        super(DynamicEmbeddedDocument, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Source(UtilityDocument, DynamicDocument):

    source = StringField(required=True)
    sourceName = StringField(required=True)
    supportedDataTypes = ListField(StringField())
    devices = ListField(StringField())
    connectedSince = DateTimeField()
    externalId = StringField()
    historySync = EmbeddedDocumentField(HistorySync)
    syncStatus = EmbeddedDocumentField(SyncStatus)
```

The main document (Source) is able to save fine throughout my web app, but whenever I try to access a Source document with statements such as

```
Source.objects.first()
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 264, in first
        result = queryset[0]
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 163, in __getitem__
        only_fields=self.only_fields)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 725, in _from_son
        raise InvalidDocumentError(msg)
    InvalidDocumentError: Invalid data to create a `Source` instance.
    syncStatus - 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
class Source(UtilityDocument, DynamicDocument):
    syncStatus = EmbeddedDocumentField(SyncStatus)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(DynamicDocument, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):` 
        return str(self.syncStatus)

    @property
    def syncStatus(self):
        return str(self.syncStatus)
```

which will convert the property into string when returned.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me because it did not allow me to initialize documents. I'll keep looking for an answer and would be happy to try anything else.

Comment: Try using custom `def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):` to initialize the parent classes and provide any custom logic for the child initializer.